# XAML - Declare string, with Textbox.Text as value

Tags: string, xaml, variables

kinda new to XAML, but I was wondering if it's possible to declare a string variable which contains the value of a Textbox.Text.

```
<System:String x:Key="AlarmMessage01">
     <!-- Textbox text goes here --->           
</System:String>
```

I'm not looking for a solution which depends on code-behind, purely XAML code, and I don't want to enter a static value either.

Can this even be done, and if so could you show me an example?

Kind regards Cvr

Answer (score 0):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="myStaticString" >Hello World</x:String>
</Page.Resources>



<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource myStaticString}" />
```

I have tested it in WinRT or Windows Store projects

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a value that can be updated dynamically, you can use Dynamic Resources or Data Binding

With Data Binding(this is probably the best approach):

In your ViewModel class:

```
public string TextBoxValue { get; set; }

public ViewModel(string text)
{
    TextBoxValue = text;
}
```

In your Code-Behind:

```
public CurrentPage()
{
    this.BindingContext = new ViewModel("Text to be displayed");
}
```

In your XAML file:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBoxValue}" />
```

And that's that about it.

Meanwhile, if you want to go with Dynamic Resources:

In code-behind file(wherever you want to update the value), you have:

```
this.Resources["myStringValue"] = "Text to be displayed";
```

And in XAML, you have:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource myStringValue}" />
```